# The Perpetual Teapot (no.28)

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge

So, as I stated in my first `Teapot` riddle, I was challenged by a [fellow user](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/42452/user477343) to create a `Teapot` riddle, and thus I have created two (numbers 26 and 27). However, to put my traditional stamp on it, I've decided to create one more. Welcome to the Perpetual Teapot!

---

### The Rules

- I have one word which has several (2 or more) meanings.
- Each of the meanings is a teapot (first, second ...).
- You try to figure out the word with my hints.
- I will post a new hint everyday; with each hint making it easier to solve.

---

### The Puzzle

Since this one will probably expand quite a bit, I'm going to use a different format to keep the post as short and clean as possible.

> - My first teapot is a small stream.
> - My second teapot is the average type of something.
> - My third teapot is a rapid series of notes forming a scale.

---

### Bonus Reputation Opportunity

I will award $50$ reputation if you can explain why I chose the word.

---

Good luck to you all and have fun!

Comment: Damn, I was gonna say what @Rasco mentioned in his/her answer. $(+1)$ though :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a ...

> Run

First teapot -

> Run is the name of small streams in North America and is also a name of a stream in the Dutch province of Noord-Brabant.

Second teapot -

> Going for a run is an average type of exercise to get in shape with.  One might say its a pretty common exercise.

Third teapot -

> A run in musical terms is a rapid series of ascending or descending musical notes often closely spaced in pitch forming a scale.

Edited to remove initial guess of...

> Headwaters

Comment: That was awesome for the second teapot and very interesting for the first lol. +1 from me, but not the answer.

Comment: @PerpetualJ Yay I figured I had it after the musical clue.  Did you choose this word because you were trying to procrastinate going on a *blank* yourself?

Comment: Haha no, I wouldn't consider that unless I was sick! Feel free to take another crack at that. There's something special about this word!

Comment: @PerpetualJ did you think of this word because a newspaper/ magazine recently *blank* and article about you.  Or did you recently decide you would become a candidate in a political election?

Im greedy for those 50 rep points but if I don't get it with either of those guesses I might need another hint hahaa

Comment: That wasn't it either lol it has this in common with the word *set*. Another hint would be too search *blank definition* on Google and scroll down in amazement at how many teapots there actually are.

Comment: rot 13("Frg" unf 464 qrsvavgvbaf va gur Bksbeq Ratyvfu Qvpgvbanel. "Eha" ehaf n qvfgnag frpbaq, jvgu 396) ah HA

Comment: There you go lol so you can imagine, I could have taken this on for quite some time lol Ensure you add it to your answer and I'll award the bounty when it allows me to!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83649/discussion-between-jim-and-perpetualj).

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> CURRENT?

Meanings:

> "The swiftest part of a stream". "Generally accepted, used, practiced, or prevalent at the moment".

Comment: Good attempt but it doesn't seem to fit the second teapot.